# Firebase Push Notification when a new child is added to the Database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

i want to have a notification every time a new child as been created in the Firebase database. This is what i got so far. With this line of code you recive a notification when a new child has been created. But the problem is that the notification always with the Title: "Title", Body: "Come check it" is. Now is my question how i can created a notification with the value City and Time (See the structure below)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database.ref('/Rollerbanken/{Id}').onCreate(event => {

    const payload = {
    notification: {
    title: 'Title',
    body: 'come check it',
    badge: '0',
    sound: 'default',
    }
};
    return admin.database().ref('fcmToken').once('value').then(allToken => {
    if(allToken.val()) {
    const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {
            });
        };
    });
});
```

My Structure:

```
{
  "Rollerbanken" : {
    "-KuKDXL2pY9MMtw551ZI" : {
      "Extrainformatie" : "",
      "Latitude" : "51.9145932124898",
      "Longitude" : "5.86974696138047",
      "Staater" : "Staat er",
      "Staaternietmeer" : "",
      "City" : "Overbetuwe",
      "Time" : "15 : 43",
      "TijdControle" : "15 : 43",
      "TijdControleniet" : "",
      "TypeControle" : "Rollerbank"
    }
  }
```

I hope you can help me!

Comment: You might want to look into Cloud Functions for Firebase and write a database trigger that uses the admin SDK to send a notification when a location in the database changes.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to modify your payload object for each notification you want to send. The good news is since its just an object you can access it easily, so all you have to do is `payload.name = YOURDESIREDVALUEHERE`

So what you need to do is take your new key, (token) and use it to access your object. Unless i'm mistaken Object.keys generates an array, so your access key should be token[0], then use that to access your value, like this `allToken.val()[token[0]]["City"]`

Your code would look like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database.ref('/Rollerbanken/{Id}').onCreate(event => {

    const payload = {
    notification: {
    title: 'Title',
    body: 'come check it',
    badge: '0',
    sound: 'default',
    }
};
    return admin.database().ref('fcmToken').once('value').then(allToken => {
    if(allToken.val()) {
    const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
    payload.notification.title = allToken.val()[token[0]]["City"] + allToken.val()[token[0]]["Time"] //change here
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: It isnt sending any notifications anymore.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l61K8.png This is the error that it is getting

Comment: Oh that would do it, i didn't notice payload is a nested object. you just need to access payload.notification.title. Edited again.

Comment: No worries, (and its javascript, not java, they are *very* different languages), basically i didn't notice your title property was inside an object that was inside the payload object, so I wasn't accessing the property I thought i was.

Comment: I still got errors. It also wont send notifications https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UvKy.png

Comment: Please help me!

Comment: console.log(payload.notification.title) on the line below "change here", and see what the title is, but the error is very explicity, what you're putting in there has to be a string, and is most likely not, find a way to convert those values to a string. While i'm happy to help, if you ever want to succeed in development/coding, you have to figure out how to work from the error messages.